# casting values from bigint array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

my data is in the form

```
id| x
int|bigint[]
_______
1 |{3}
________
2 |{4}
_____
4 |{7}
```

i need to use the values in the big int array for another join, how can i remove the curly braces and use them as an int?

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Comment: yes, i am using postgras

Comment: You can access an array element using e.g. `x[1]` for the first element. But it's unclear to me how exactly you want to join. And what if your array contains more than one value? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and also add some sample data for the table you want to join to and the expected output based on that data as  ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

example with unnest

```
select *
from (
  select id, unnest(x)::integer as x
  from data
) as data

left join data2
on data2.x = data.x
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8f2412b6ca21f1251b3b9810f8f4a593

example with `&&`. More performance efficient with GIN index, than `unnest`

```
select *
from data
left join data2
on ARRAY[data2.x] && data.x::integer[]
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=21c49b4755c5395c88324e58b91b1624

Answer (score 1):

Often you don't need restructure the data.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select . . .
from data d join
     t
     on t.x = any (d.x)
```